# How many request for scraping can handle ScrapyRT

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd, web-scripting

I have a single project with the web interface where I should download from `3000` to `20000` urls per week (month). I use tickets system for showing a progress: what is downloaded, what is pending for downloading, which urls have timeout errors and similar issues. Now I'm using `ScrapyD` for it, but planning to switch to `ScrapyRT`. Because it's looking easier to run single URL and getting a result after it - updates ticket status.
My question is how many independent requests can receive `ScrapyRT`? I tried near 50-100 request for scraping async and server just stop work.

Or there exist some another way how to do it? Scrapy cluster or Frontera is not for me